# Linksys wireless NIC won't reconnect after coming out of hibernate

Tags: wifi, drivers, linksys

I recently bought a Linksys WMP110 wireless PCI NIC for my XP machine. It works fine, except when I take it out of hibernate it sometimes won't reconnect or even see any wireless networks. I have to reboot for it to work again.

I figured there might be a driver setting that can be tweaked to fix it, but I'm not sure what that setting might be. I'm using the latest driver for the card (1.1.2). I have a built-in Ethernet interface and a regular PCI Ethernet card in the machine, but both are disabled. Any idea why this would randomly happen?

Comment: See this for similar problem - http://serverfault.com/questions/11765/linksys-wusb300n-usb-wifi-adapter-doesnt-wakeup

Comment: On a sidenote, this card will cause troubles under Linux. The madwifi project is currently developing a new driver, so there's hope.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to check is that the computer is not set to turn it of to save power:

- Open device manager
- Expand Network Adapters, right-click your Linksys Wireless device, and then click Properties.
- Click the Power Management tab.
- The Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power check box is displayed, make sure it is unchecked.

Comment: I don't actually have a Power Management tab when I go to the properties dialog for the wireless NIC. There's an Advanced tab with a couple dozen NIC-specific settings. I tried changing one labeled CAM When AC Power to Enabled, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Vista, but not XP. When I would come out of hibernate, it would take 5-10 minutes to connect back to the wireless. I disabled Ipv6 and it sped the process to 2-5 minutes! In my mind, that was still too long. The next idea I tried was to disable the security on my wireless router. That fixed the problem instantly. I WAS using WPA2, but it takes so long to reconnect so I had to downgrade to WPA. I know this is a bad idea, but I couldn't take the delay anymore.

Comment: The network I'm connecting to isn't mine, and they are using WEP. I would try to get WPA working but I don't want to make major changes to the network. I have a feeling if I waited long enough mine would reconnect as well, since if I try to repair the connection it starts to work. I'll probably have to live with not hibernating for now.

Comment: Try disabling IPv6.